# Debugger in RubyMine - Frame is not available

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubymine

Im using Rubymine 7.1.5, Im super new to it, and was learning step by step, watching video tutorials, when I encountered that debugging in my program isn't working.

This is screenshot of what it looks like to me: http://prntscr.com/ij0mvr

The guy in tutorial didn't have this problem(tho video is like 5years old). I have no idea where to even start as Im newb.

Comment: Which Ruby version are you using?

Comment: If you use Ruby 2.3.3 you need DevKit to load C Extension before starting your debugger!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I freaking didn't put any stoppoints, like this http://prntscr.com/ijqmzp
Thats why it wasn't working, I hope this will help some other curious newb like me ;)

Comment: Which Ruby Version are you using? you need Dev Kit if you use Ruby 2.3.3.

Answer (score 2):

For me this happens when I put an ampersand into the test name, like:

```rb
test "#this & that" do
  # Any breakpoints here will be ignored: Frames are not available and there is a Thread 1 [sleep] :/
end
```

Removing the ampersand solves it though.

Comment: Reproducable with current RubyMine 2022.3 and `ruby-debug-ide 3.0.0.beta.5`: placing a double quote into a test name will make the problem appear:


`test 'GET / with unknown param "post" '`

Removing the double quote lets the debugger hit the breakpoint again

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a problem that the debugger was running, but it was not stopping to the breakpoints. Also there was an error message on the stack trace: "Frame is not available". The setup was Vagrant virtual machine with Rubymine **Remote Debug**. The problem was, that the remote root path was relatively not the same as the local folder. Please double check Run -> Edit Configurations and in your configuration that these two settings are pointing to the same files relatively:

- Remote root folder
- Local root folder

I had these settings as "/vagrant" (the shared folder inside vagrant) and "/home/myuser/project-root/tests". Taking the "tests" away (in my case) solved the problem, as the files were matching.

I found the issue by running the debugger, and then clicking pause. I saw that it was executing my code, showed the variable state, but not the file name it was paused at.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging tests, Make sure you run only one worker:
`test_helper.rb`

```
parallelize(workers: 1)
```